# Use of has and have with multiple examples

Tags: grammatical-number, have

I wonder if someone could clarify this for me

His anger and irritation have or has affected me.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1):

if you are considering the anger and irritation to be two separate things, then, clearly you would use 'have'. If they are one thing, then you could explicitly join them e.g. His angry and irritated behaviour/mood/manner has affected me.

Comment: *The combination of his anger and irritation* ***has*** *affected me*. :)